# Laravel Eloquent Remove With

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have the following models.

```
Person
Address
Visit
```

A person has the following relationships.

```
$this->hasMany Orders
$this->hasMany Addresses
$this->hasMany Visits
```

A visit has the following relationship

```
$this->hasMany('App\Person')->with('Addresses');
```

If I load all orders on a day and specify with Person

```
return \App\Order::whereDate('date_ordered',\Carbon\Carbon::today())->with('Person')->get();
```

I automatically receive the "addresses" from the Person model relationship as this is defined on the model, is there a way to remove this on this particular call?

Comment: You could add another relation to `App\Person` without the `->with('Addresses')` part

Comment: I could but I wondered if there was a programmatical way because I would then have PersonNoAddresses lol XD

Comment: What's wrong with `PersonNoAddresses`? Call it `PersonOnly`. ;) Depends on if you might need this relation in other places later on. If not try OMR's answer

Comment: That's true, I have used this method before, i'll give OMR's answer ago but thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [without](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default):

```
    \App\Order::whereDate('date_ordered',\Carbon\Carbon::today())->with(['Person'=>function($query){
$query->without('Addresses');
}])->get();
```

PS: you should make all your 'with' before get() method, not after

Comment: I've updated the question to put the with before the get(), regarding the without() will this not simply remove the relationships on the Order model and not the Person?

Comment: It appears without() will only remove direct relationships on the Order model not the with() on the Person relationship

Comment: even the nested one?

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Didn't realize I could filter further into nested.